# Remember me functionality in custom session object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-timeout, remember-me

I am developing an asp.net mvc application in which I keep user credentials in session object. Which is initiated in global asax session start method. And have a statik class to get or set. How can I add a remember me functionality. Is it based on form authentication of asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you probably want Forms Authentication. You use attributes like `[Authorize]` to "protect" the controllers that you need to log in for, and provide a new Controller for log-on stuff. Don't think this setup requires you to do much/anything in the global asax file or in the session.

Here's a start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049.aspx

The tutorial assumes you used the "New MVC app" template, where login features are set up by default. Probably there are more tutorials on this topic, the search query "MVC Forms Authentication Tutorial" should get you there. Surely some of them include setting up the basic web.config stuff as well.

Comment: Jeroen thanks for your quick reply. Form authentication ticket just provide user role to save in cookie? Am I right? How to keep other information in cookie to provide remember me?

Comment: Aye, somewhere along the line you can call [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) that handles most of the trouble for you. If you choose to use the basic setup template in Visual Studio that call shall already be there for you, I think.

Answer (score 1):

you can save a user name in cookie and in session other information. when you need other information you check are they in session. if not you can get them from db based on user name from cookie and save in session.

Comment: Fro how about if i need to more than username to provide credential to login. i need both which website user loggedin. how can i keep multiple cookie for that user. my app is actually multiple web site which run on same code. I am check security for user based on url he entered.

Comment: what i know in the cookie is save information which domain it come from. im not 1oo% sure but i think cookies shouldn't interfere with each other.